# Регулярное выражение. Условие 5 не повторяющихся цифр от 1 до 5

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

необходимо проверить удовлетворяет ли строка условию. т.е. нужно чтобы строки имели следующий вид 12345, 52413, 12543 и т.д.

Ошибочными считаются строки 11234(повторение), 12347(7 не попадает в диапазон 1-5).

мое решение только проверяет чтобы все было в заданном диапазоне и длиной 5 символов.

`[1-5]{5}`

Comment: `([1-5])(?!\1)([1-5])(?!\1|\2)([1-5])(?!\1|\2|\3)([1-5])(?!\1|\2|\3|\4)([1-5])`

Comment: @Alexandr: А почему обязательно регулярка? Вы, надеюсь, понимаете, что решение без регулярки будет намного понятнее и легче в поддержке и отладке.

Comment: @VladD Нет желания писать много кода ради проверки одного textbox
прошлый коммент работает. добавьте как ответ

Comment: @Alexandr: Вы реально думаете, что с регуляркой вы _сэкономите_? «Now, you have two problems» (c)

Comment: Вот так тоже можно, вполне удобочитаемо (для меня): [`^(?:(1)|(2)|(3)|(4)|(5)){5}$(?<-1>)(?<-2>)(?<-3>)(?<-4>)(?<-5>)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f%3a%281%29%7c%282%29%7c%283%29%7c%284%29%7c%285%29%29%7b5%7d%5cr%3f%24%28%3f%3c-1%3e%29%28%3f%3c-2%3e%29%28%3f%3c-3%3e%29%28%3f%3c-4%3e%29%28%3f%3c-5%3e%29&i=12345%0d%0a52413%0d%0a12543%0d%0a%0d%0a11234%0d%0a12234%0d%0a12334%0d%0a12347&o=m).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
s.Length == 5 && s.All(c => c >= '1' && c <= '5') && s.Distinct().Count() == 5
```

Это будет короче чем проверять регуляркой и гораздо понятнее

Ещё один вариант:

```
new string(s.OrderBy(c => c).ToArray()) == "12345"
```

Эквивалент предыдущего, но еще короче (и без создания новой строки — быстрее):

```
s.OrderBy(c => c).SequenceEqual("12345")
```